# MVC - Nested Partial Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting an error ("*Server Error in '/' Application*") when I nest partial views in my `MVC` app.  The views work fine individually, but not when nested.  It's my understanding that it's okay to do this, so what am I doing wrong?

Essentially, I am trying to use partials as sub-layouts within my `_Layout.cshtml`.

Here's my main layout - `_Layout.cshtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body style="padding-top: 80px;">  
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="myTab" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                ...
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="search">
                       @Html.Partial("~/Areas/Search/Views/Shared/_SearchLayout.cshtml")
                    </div>                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @RenderBody()
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

This is the first partial view (_SearchLayout).  If I remove the partials AND @RenderBody, no error.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        @Html.Partial("_PolicySearch")
        @Html.Partial("_ClaimSearch")       
    </div>
@RenderBody()
```

This partial view is nested in the first partial view (_SearchLayout):

```
 <div class="row top-buffer search-outline form-horizontal">
        <div class="col-md-1 search-icon-size text-primary">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 search-icon-size text-primary">
            <h4>Claim Search</h4>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

Comment: in your controller for the partials do you by chance use return View() rather than return PartialView()

Comment: I am not using a controller for these partial views, they are shared.

Answer (score 2):

In your first partial view:

1. Remove RenderBody
2. Replace Html.Partial to Html.RenderPartial

I also would  recommend to rename your partial view to something not containing the word "Layout" to avoid the mismatch between the view types.

Comment: There is zero difference between using `Html.Partial` and `Html.RenderPartial`, at least as far as this question is concerned. Anecdotal evidence suggests that `Html.RenderPartial` may be slightly more performant, but functionally they're exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use Html.RenderPartial instead

Comment: Where are the partial views located? You need to write the path in the same way as the first one @{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Areas/Search/Views/BLAH/BLAH/_PolicySearch")}

Comment: And realize that you need to call it whitin braces @{ Html.RenderPartial("ViewName");  }

Comment: They are all in the same folder.  I tried this - @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Areas/Search/Views/Shared/_PolicySearch.cshtml")} and this @{Html.RenderPartial("_PolicySearch")}.  Neither one works.

Comment: You missed this @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Areas/Search/Views/Shared/_PolicySearch")}

Comment: Tried that and no help. Thanks

Comment: @dariogriffo...Render works fine, but you are correct about using the path to the partial view within the child view.  Even though the partial view and its children are in the same folder, I needed to do this: @Html.Partial("~/Areas/Search/Views/Shared/_PolicySearch.cshtml")

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `@RenderBody()`. This can only be called in a layout, which when used in this way `_SearchLayout.cshtml` is *not*, despite its name.

The important thing to remember about layouts, partials and views in ASP.NET MVC is that they're *all* views. The only thing that differentiates them is *how they're used*. In this instance, you're using the `_SearchLayout.cshtml` view as a partial, and partials can't use `@RenderBody()`.

Comment: This is what I thought, but when I remove the @RenderBody() and leave the partial views, I still get the error.

Comment: Then there's some *other* problem at play. You should be getting a yellow screen of death with a stacktrace assuming this is happening in development. If you're in production, you should use something like ELMAH to log errors for you so you can still see the stacktraces there. Alternatively, if you have Visual Studio 2013, you can do remote debugging. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx. Short of that, you can always just add `<customErrors mode="Off" />` temporarily to your Web.config, but that can be kind of dangerous in production.

Comment: No yellow screen of death and Elmah responds with "No errors found".  Fiddler shows a 302 response "<h2>Object moved to <a href="/Error/?aspxerrorpath=/">here</a>.</h2>" followed by a 500. I'm very confused.

Comment: Is this only occurring in production, or do you see the behavior in development as well? If you can replicate it in development debug and use breakpoints to try to pinpoint the failure (add one right before the partial call, then inside the partial, etc.). Keep going until you can find the exact line where all hell breaks loose.